# Strange lines between horizontal bars in Chart.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have some strange lines between horizontal bars in Chart.js.
Even if i put  `barPercentage: 1,` `categoryPercentage: 1,`.
I also tried all combination of [0.90, 1]. Please help!

Here is what i have

[image]

```js
  new Chart(elem, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: data.map(i => REGIONS[i.region]),
      datasets: [{
        data: data.map(i => i[name]),
      }],
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
          padding: 20,
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            // lineWidth: 0,
            drawTicks: false,
            drawBorder: false,
            // zeroLineWidth: 1,
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          barPercentage: .99, // I've also tried all from [0.90, 1]
          categoryPercentage: .98, // I've also tried all from [0.90, 1]
          ticks: {
            padding: 25,
          },
        }]
      },
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried your code with some sample data, I am getting the proper result, I am using the latest `Chart.js` (Version 2.7.0) and it works fine when I set `barPercentage` and the `categoryPercentage` to 1, If you still face this issue,

My major point in this answer is!

> The values `barPercentage` and the `categoryPercentage` can be
>   increased above `1` so you can give `1.05` to resolve this problem.

Here is a JSFiddle with some sample data I mocked up to show solution.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Please feel free to try this solution, if the above suggestions don't work, please replicate the problem in the JSFiddle I provided and show me the issue again!

Comment: @ІвченкоДима Does this help you?

Comment: Yes. Thanks u a lot. My mistake was that I use  `barPercentage, categoryPercentage` not both equal to 1. So the combination for both with float gave that problem.